# Search locations of strings in text file

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a text file (`file1`) with **rows containing string entries**. The first element of each row corresponds to a label, while all the subsequent entries of each row contain strings. It is possible that same strings may feature at different locations in multiple rows. Different rows in `file1` have different numbers of columns.

Consider this as an example of `file1` (you can download `file1` from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1te3qcKI9NFicE9i_0WwnMS2vpUc6EXS4/view?usp=sharing)):

```
label1: aa  bb  dd  zz  yy  ww
label2: pp  qq  aa  ss
label3: mm  aa  gg  qq  rr  kk
label4: uu  ss  ll  pp
label5: hh  jj  qq  ss  uu
```

Independent of `file1`, I have a **one dimensional numpy array** (`arr`) which contains **strings** (**unique entries**). Each string in `arr` finds mention in one or more rows of `file1` (entries in file1 except for the first column). Consider the following as an example of `arr`.

```
arr = np.array(['aa', 'qq', 'ss', 'zz', 'ss', 'pp', 'dd'])
```

**Using python**, I want to compare `arr` with `file1`, and **find indices of strings** in `arr` **which are similar**. Following example illustrates how I want to decide the similarity: if entry1, entry4 and entry5 of `arr` feature in the same row of `file1` then I want to get a tuple (or list) with the indices of these entries `(1,4,5)`. I want to do this for all such groups.

In the example for `arr` and `file1` given above , we see that `('aa', 'dd', 'zz')` exist in the first row of `file1` (so I would want to have the tuple `(0,3,6)`. )  Similarly `('ss', 'pp')` from `arr` feature in the fourth row of `file1`, so I would like to have the tuple `(4,5)` also. Finally, `('qq', 'ss')` being in fifth row of `file1` would lead to the tuple `(1,2)`.

Presently, I encounter error when I try to read `file1.txt` using `np.genfromtxt('file1.txt')`

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 5 columns instead of 7)
    Line #4 (got 5 columns instead of 7)
    Line #5 (got 6 columns instead of 7)
```

How can I read `file1` properly and achieve the result that I want? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `np.genfromtxt` is an array, so the fact that the number of columns in each row vary means you have to appropriately deal with missing values.  You might consider just iterating over the file with `csv`, but another option would be to just use `pd.read_csv` like this

```
> pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep=r'\s+', header=None, dtype='|U').values[:,1:]
> array([['aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'zz', 'yy', 'ww'],
         ['pp', 'qq', 'aa', 'ss', nan, nan],
         ['mm', 'aa', 'zz', 'qq', 'rr', 'dd'],
         ['uu', 'ss', 'll', 'pp', nan, nan],
         ['hh', 'jj', 'qq', 'ss', 'uu', nan]], dtype=object)
```

If performance is  important, and the strings are indeed  all two characters, you could set `dtype='|S2'` in the constructor.   Depending on the version of `pandas` you have, you may also need to set `engine='python'` to avoid getting warnings about the regular expression (don't do that unless you run into trouble though, it is slower and may be unnecessary).

Your `arr` has a duplicate element in it at 2 and 4, but supposing that's right the whole thing would look like this:

```
In [1] a=pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep=r'\s+', header=None).values[:,1:].astype('<U2')
In [2] arr = np.array(['aa', 'qq', 'ss', 'zz', 'ss', 'pp', 'dd'])
In [3] [tuple(j for j, el in enumerate(arr) if el in set(a[i])) for i in range(len(a))]
Out[4] [(0, 3, 6), (0, 1, 2, 4, 5), (0, 1, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (1, 2, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as there was a request to solve it on Python, without mentioning Pandas:

> Using **python**, I want to compare arr with file1, and ...

I can suggest straightforward working algorithm:

```
arr = ['aa', 'qq', 'ss', 'zz', 'ss', 'pp', 'dd']
with open('file.csv') as inp:
    for line in inp.readlines(): # scan csv line by line
        words = line.strip().split(' ') # split line to words
        label = words[0]   # get label
        items = words[1:]  # get all but label
        lst = []           # result tuple/list for this line
        for i in range(len(arr)):   
            if arr[i] in items and arr.index(arr[i]) == i:
                lst.append(i)
        print ('{}: {}'.format(label, lst))
```

Note, `arr.index(arr[i]) == i` checks that item in array is not duplicated